# easy way to break off pieces of baking chocolate

Tags: food

We buy a block of baking chocolate of 5 kg around 10 pounds. When we want to use the chocolate it's always a hassle to break off a piece. It's  a block 5 cm thick (2 inches). I need a easier way to break off just the amount we need.

Comment: The block is smooth or it's similar to a simple chocolate bar?

Comment: The block is 45cm X 24cm it has like indentation for blocks of 500 grams thick 5 cm. What do you mean by smooth?

Comment: Easier? What are you doing now?

Comment: Try to cut, break off . It's not easy and I end up short or to much. I asked this question if someone has a better way to get the amount needed in a reliable way without being cut, or break other things and have the right amount needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will get better suggestions on Seasoned Advice (the Stack exchange for professional and amateur chefs).

But apart from chopping off a large chunk by using a knife/chisel and a blunt tool like a hammer, you could also heat the knife and melt-cut the piece you want (I don't see a problem with doing it, although there might be, because of the nature of chocolate).

Answer (score 2):

Use a chocolate slicer

Chocolate slicers are specially designed to chop chocolate. One can be purchased on Amazon, or at a cooking supply store. It looks like a tiny pitchfork and is usually around $5. This is a good method if you find it takes too much force to cut the chocolate with a knife. A chocolate chipper requires less force and power. This might just be a worthwhile investment if you regularly cut chunks of chocolate. Ice axes look similar and do the same job.

Comment: Hi Marvin, Welcome to Lifehacks. The Lifehack for what you suggest is a heavy/sturdy fork. That's what I used last night on a chocolate berg to get parts to make hot chocolate. Thanks for the reference and link. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I never knew that such an item exists, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 options.

1. Add your own indentations. That is, figure out the size you need, and score it to that size with a serrated knife (like a large bread knife). It should break off very easily that way.
2. Another option is to chip the whole giant block into small pieces, which you can store in tightly-sealed plastic bags or plastic containers. Then, when you need a certain weight, just pour out the right amount of the small chips you made.

Comment: I'm working with the second method, and it's very comfortable (although with regular blocks, but it's still comfortable to have it pre-chopped to when I need it)

Comment: An additional plus is that you could eat the chips as they are.